# How to refer to enum from swift package with same name as struct in project

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have a struct in my project named `Location`.  My project uses a swift package named `LocationPackage`, which defines an enum `Location`.  How can I refer to the `LocationPackage` enum `Location` instead of my project's struct?

In the LocationPackage package we have:

```
public enum Location: String {
    case location1
    case location2
}
```

In our project we have:

```
struct Location {
    let name: String?
    let placeID: String?
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

When I try to use `LocationPackage.Location`, I get a compiler error `Location is not a member type of 'LocationPackage'`.

One workaround I found was adding `public typealias LocationPackageLocation = Location` in the location package.

Comment: Apparently you are the owner of the package. If so why don't you simply rename one of the types for example `LocationType` for the enum?

Comment: Sure I could.  But I still want to know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have conflicting names in Swift modules then it will prefer your current modules type of that name if it exists. To access the others you must always disambiguate by using the module name. In this case that means you need to use `LocationPackage.Location` to access your `Location` enum.

Comment: That's what I expected to be able to do, but I get `Location is not a member of type LocationPackage`

Comment: Do you have a module name and type naming collision? Your module names shouldn’t match type names or you can’t disambiguite.

Comment: Nope different names